Inserting IANA TLD file into SQL Database in C# (File too long)
I want to insert the TLDs of the IANA file (https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) into a column of a SQL table via C#, but it is too long.
Column is defined as NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype.
It always throws

System.Exception: No closing quotation mark after the string "..."

I separated the file and let it read via
string[] batches = File.ReadAllText(scriptFile)
                       .Split(new[] { "GO" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

but it throws the same error.
What to do?
This is the structure of the SQL file:
IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MediaSettings 
    WHERE [Key] = 'TopLevelDomains') = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MediaSettings (ID, Name, [Key], Value, CreateDate)
    VALUES (NEWID(), 'TopLevelDomains', 'TopLevelDomains', 'AAA,...,BAIDU', GETDATE())
END

IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MediaSettings 
    WHERE [Key] = 'TopLevelDomains') > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE MediaSettings
    SET Value = CONCAT(Value, ',BANAMEX,...,DELL')
    WHERE [Key] = 'TopLevelDomains'
END


your code is runs fine. (ufter update clean up https://dbfiddle.uk/p7Z4u-fQ)

You are splitting on the letter combination "GO". Are you sure that this letter combination does not appear in the middle of your SQL query somewhere? Perhaps adding line breaks ("\n" and/or "\r") around "GO" will help.

I don't get it, is the file you're inserting an sql file, or a csv file? Why not print the code you're running and see where it goes wrong?
